# PixiJS Animation displayed but not playing

Tags: angular, pixi.js

I just started using PixiJS's animated spreadsheet. I'm currently able to load the canvas with a background and display the first frame of the animation, but the animation itself is not being played once the page loads. Animation object seems to contain the 3 textures so not sure what I did wrong. Here'S the code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer();
    this.canvas.nativeElement.appendChild(this.renderer.view);
    this.renderer.resize(this.canvas.nativeElement.offsetHeight, this.canvas.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
    this.renderer.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;
    this.renderer.clearBeforeRender = true;

    PIXI.Loader.shared.add("assets/animation/attack.json").load(v => {
      this.sheet = PIXI.Loader.shared.resources["assets/animation/attack.json"].spritesheet
      this.playAnimation()
    });     }

  playAnimation(){
    this.stage.addChild(new DBackground());
    let animatedSprite = new PIXI.AnimatedSprite(this.sheet.animations["attack1"]);
    // set speed, start playback and add it to the stage
    animatedSprite.animationSpeed = 1; 
    animatedSprite.position.set(100, 100);
    console.log(animatedSprite) // Here initialized and contains my 3 textures
    this.stage.addChild(animatedSprite);
    this.renderer.render(this.stage);
    animatedSprite.play();   } //tried moving the play before and after adding to stage to no effect
```

and the animation JSON:

```
{"frames": {

"attack1_01.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":124,"h":150},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":124,"h":150},
    "sourceSize": {"w":124,"h":150},
    "anchor": {"x":0.5,"y":0.5}
},
"attack1_02.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":0,"y":150,"w":124,"h":150},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":124,"h":150},
    "sourceSize": {"w":124,"h":150},
    "anchor": {"x":0.5,"y":0.5}
},
"attack1_03.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":0,"y":300,"w":124,"h":150},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":124,"h":150},
    "sourceSize": {"w":124,"h":150},
    "anchor": {"x":0.5,"y":0.5}
}},
"animations": {
    "attack1": ["attack1_01.png","attack1_02.png","attack1_03.png"]
},
"meta": {
    "app": "https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker",
    "version": "1.0",
    "image": "attack.png",
    "format": "RGBA8888",
    "size": {"w":124,"h":450},
    "scale": "1",
    "smartupdate": "$TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:63b741f3788ee57673ebd4ed24263f9f:6273cec99c87913aa3f143bf4818a5da:c558c2d9773adf0f4ef6f0e9687f205f$"
}
}
```

please let me know if you see anything that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Your animation is indeed playing but you are rendering the canvas only once. The call to `this.renderer.render(this.stage)` needs to be placed in a loop, typically like:

```js
render() {
  this.renderer.render(this.stage);
  requestAnimationFrame(this.render);
}
```